# speed up if loop in a range - vba

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I need VBA code that will color a cell when text condition is met. Right now my code is not efficient, maybe because of the full range of column E where the loop is searching. The thing is that I'll always have a different range of used cells in column E. Can you help speed up the code?

```vba
Sub color_status()
   Dim cell As Range
   
   For Each cell In Range("E:E")
      If cell.value = "Open" Then
         cell.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180)
      ElseIf cell.value = "In Progress" Then
         cell.Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)
      ElseIf cell.value = "Done" Then
         cell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71)
      ElseIf cell.value = "On Hold" Then
         cell.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
      End If
   Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest to use conditional formatting for that.

Comment: I don't believe what you are saying: you say that you need VBA code (instead of conditional formatting). This means that the colours of the cell can only be altered once you decide it, so a solution, modifying the colour without any action from you would be wrong. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

```vb
Sub color_status()

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, s As String, dict As Object
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add "Open", RGB(198, 224, 180)
        .Add "In Progress", RGB(169, 208, 142)
        .Add "Done", RGB(112, 173, 71)
        .Add "On Hold", RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("E:E"))
    End With

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cel In rng
            s = Trim(cel.Value)
            If dict.exists(s) Then
                cel.Interior.Color = dict(s)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    MsgBox rng.Rows.Count & " rows scanned", _
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Range ("E:E:) is too large to loop - it's about 1 million of cells

1 variant
Limit it using UsedRange and loop via index:

```
    Dim Ecount as Long, i as Long
    Ecount=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    
    For i=1 to Ecount
if Cells(i,5)= "Open" Then
    '(etc. your code inside the loop)
    Next i
```

or 2 variant

```
Dim lRange as Range
lRange=Range(Cells(1,5),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count,5))
'then loop as you do with the lRange
For each cell in lRange
        '(etc. your code inside the loop)
Next cell
```

As for me, use cells index to loop is eacier for debug- when you debug you know the row number immediately

Comment: `Set lRange= ...`. Note `Usedrange` may not start in row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Excel file, based on the values you provided, but I used conditional formatting. This is the result:

[image]

As it's not done using VBA, the performance is instantaneous, but I'm wondering if your RGB values are correct :-)